# How to make async messaging fast and reliable in a sync environment?

Tags: distributed-system, system-design

I have an backend API application which does its job and and generates some evential data, which can be offloaded asynchronously. It's sent to services with mostly through RESTful interfaces, such as SQS, Elasticsearch, our own services (also asynchronous yet behind HTTP). App is PHP so the job cannot be offloaded in a different thread - the whole process just dies after it responds, and the client must wait while the data is sent to the remote services.

The problem is that transferring data **at least once** is unreliable and slow in this setup. For instance, SQS often responds with an error and it requires to do a retry during the request lifetime. Most importantly, it's slower than it could be and sometimes there aren't enough retries to succeed (some data loss).

I was thinking about a service agent: a simple daemon, which is baked into the docker container along with the app, hence running on the same host. This local daemon would somehow accept payloads from the app and then do the communications and retries. I know some software works this way, but isn't there something more general already existing, like a specialized proxy? Or are there techniques to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your API has a database then take a look at [Outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html). Even thought the main purpose of the pattern is ensuring data consistency in distributed systems, it allows you to offload message sending to another worker. In [this video](https://vimeo.com/111998645) Udi Dahan explains very well how it works. I'm not expert in PHP so don't know what PHP solutions exists, but it is worth checking in this direction.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's possible to put the messages into a DB with a reliable connection and same as the app availability in SLA, and then process them asynchronously. It would be basically a database-based queue. I wonder if this is a default or widespread industry practice for async communications though: the microservices architectures are very popular, and most of the time those need to communicate asynchronously, most often with "at least once" strategy. At least for a monolithic app (1 database as the source of truth), it seems to generate overly heavy load on DB, hence not so fast.

Comment: Yes, it adds a bit of overhead on DB load, but usually not big. The most widely used approach I've seen is to push messages when transaction is committed, basically same mechanism as in your case, if I understand it correct. There are different problems that might occur using this approach, well described in Udi Dahan's video and mentioned by you in the question. In such cases Outbox pattern is one of the most widely used solution for this kind of problems. You can also look into Saga pattern, but probably it would be a big change to your architecture.